# Run parallel instances of same program on Pycharm

Tags: python, json, pycharm, instance

I have a program named Scanner.py which loads parameters from a configuration file called Config.json- is there a way in which I can run two instances of this same file parallely on Pycharm with different sets of configuration passed through Config.json.

Example: this is the Json file which is read into the Python file of Pycharm. I want various combinations of this to be run without one after the other, rather in parallel

```
"Traded Instrument": "STOCK",
"Start Date": "2019/01/01",
"End Date": "2022/12/20",
"Trade Start": "09:16",
"Trade End": "15:29",
"Trade End Scalp": "09:16",
```

I do not have clue how to get started with this, other than just using different machines, but I would need more than 3/4 instances at the same time by running Scanner.py

Comment: Pycharm is an IDE, but it is not required to *execute* a Python script. And any decent OS can run a number of scripts in parallel. In Windows or any Unix-like, you can open a number of command windows and start one Python process in it. Or you can write a small Python script that would start many copies of the same program with different parameters simply with subprocess. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: If the issue is that the filename is fixed at `Config.json`, you can simply start the programs each in their own, distinct directory with their own local config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html). You can create a function that accepts a configuration dict and run it with different configs.

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool

def runner(config: dict):
    # your logic
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    configs = [{...}, {...}, {...}]
    with Pool(len(configs)) as p:
        p.map(runner, configs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say in your case it's better to make a multi-thread wrapper, simply because threading uses the same memory space, and no awaiting or such is required, whereas multi-processing uses a different memory space.

```py
from threading import Thread

def async(func: object):
    """ This is a decorator for async functions """
    def asyncFunction(*args, **kwargs):
        """ This is the wrapper function that will be returned """
        thread: Thread = Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        return thread
    return asyncFunction

@async
def runner(config: dict):
    ...
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    configs = [{...}, {...}, {...}]
    for i in range(len(configs)):
        runner(configs[i])
```

NOTE: there is a drawback to using threading, where it is not memory safe (mostly), and you cannot interrupt the program when it is doing the processing, unless you make a sort of check inside the function.

The program will look like this if you want it to work with keyboard interrupts:

```py
from threading import Thread

KeyboardInterruptDetected = False # This is a global variable that will be used to stop the program

def async(func: object):
    """ This is a decorator for async functions """
    def asyncFunction(*args, **kwargs):
        """ This is the wrapper function that will be returned """
        thread: Thread = Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.start()
        return thread
    return asyncFunction

@async
def runner(config: dict):
    if KeyboardInterruptDetected:
        return
    ... # Do something.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    configs = [{...}, {...}, {...}] # This is a list of the config dictionaries
    try:
        for config in configs:
            runner(config)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        KeyboardInterruptDetected = True
```

Comment: Your `for` loop at the end is really not very good on a couple of levels! Folks normally use underscore `_` as placeholders for *"stuff they are not interested in"*, but then you actually **use** it on the next line! And it's already totally superfluous anyway, along with `range()` and `len()`. Just use `for config in configs:`